# No Click Event by Toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I have a some problem with the toolbar in android. I get no click event when I press the navigationdrawer icon. I can only slide it.

MainActivity:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Toolbar mToolbar;
ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
RelativeLayout left_draw;

String[] title;
int[] icon;
Fragment home = new Home();
Fragment fragment_2 = new Fragment_2();
MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
private long lastBackPressTime = 0;
Toast toast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    String NAME = "Test";
    String EMAIL = "test.header@test.com";
    int PROFILE = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    // Generate title
    title = new String[]{"Home",
            "Fragment_2"};

    // Generate icon
    icon = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher};

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    left_draw = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_draw);

    // Pass string arrays to MenuListAdapter
    mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(MainActivity.this, title, icon);

    // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

    // Capture listview menu item click
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,
            R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Wenn zur�ck dann doppelt dr�cken
 */

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Um zu beenden erneut drücken", 4000);
        toast.show();
        this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        if (toast != null) {
            toast.cancel();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(left_draw)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(left_draw);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(left_draw);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// ListView click listener in the navigation drawer
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    // Locate Position
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, home);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment_2);
    }
    ft.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

    // Close drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(left_draw);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

Toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok i found my mistake it was the layout activity_main i add the DrawerLayout above the toolbar and there cant the Toolbar not handle anything. Thanks for help guys :)

Comment: out of curiosity, did you manage to make it open/close with `OnOptionsItemSelected` and `android.R.id.home` ? [I'm interested because my burger\arrow doesn't seem to be linked with this id]

Comment: Good luck.. accept your answer in order to finalize it :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a method for it:

```
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(left_draw);
        }
    });
```

If your drawer is actually covering the toolbar, that's enough - you can't press the icon to close it. If not, you need to check for the drawer state.

Comment: Also no effect by this method.

Comment: Where did you paste it? It should be after the setDrawerListener() and before the syncState() call. Try removing your onOptionsItemSelected() also.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the event to `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, if it returns true, then it has handled the app icon touch event.

So add

```
if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
    }
```

to `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(left_draw)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(left_draw);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(left_draw);
            }
        }

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I have add it but the same issue :(